Interactive R maps that work well on mobile, with inset AK and HI?
Issue: I need an interactive choropleth map of the US that will work well on mobile (ideally pinch-zoom), has a pop-up on tap/click, and has AK and HI set below. Plotly isn't it as you have to tap the tiny zoom icon, and the usmaps package shows the map I want (AK and HI below), but I can't figure out how to make it interactive with the zoom (ggplotly = plotly = not pinch-zoom). Leaflet is the reactivity I want, but I can't figure out how to get AK and HI below. The data processing is fine, it's a "How do I do the thing?" question with interactivity. DataMaps appears to have something that'd work, but it is not compatible with the version of R I have by a long shot, and is no longer updated (as of maybe 8 years ago?).
I have tried: Troubleshooting in Plotly, troubleshooting in Leaflet, spending hours doing internet searches. I can get a static map of exactly what I want in usmap, and can map it with AK and HI separated in Leaflet, but I cannot figure out how to get a US map that is more compressed and yet still interactive in the way I want it to be (it has to have a pinch-zoom or similar because of user needs). I am wondering if maybe there's a way with maybe ggiraph?
Edit: I was asked for code, and so to offer some code and an example of the map I made that I like the design of but that does not have the needed mobile interactivity (pinch-zoom):
Map prototype:
https://transformationsproject.github.io/static/widgets/map_test.html
Code (a note: I know it's messy):
tf_usa_map <- us_map(regions = "states")

# Joining so can be used 
tf_current_map <- left_join(tf_usa_map, tf_airtable_state_by_year, by=c("abbr" = "state_abb"))

# Removing DC          
tf_current_map <- tf_current_map %>%
  filter(abbr != "DC")

# Getting total count of bills for 2024
updated_total_bills <- sum(tf_current_map$`2024`)

# Building Map ----
# Setting up geometry
geo_test <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
  )

# Setting up border
state_border <- list(color = toRGB("#2d0016"), width = 2)

# Setting up custom color scale/breaks
custom_colors <- c("white", "#ed7fa1", "#DB0044", "#740024", "#410014")
custom_breaks <- c(0, 5, 20, 30, 60)


fig3 <- plot_geo(tf_current_map) %>%
  add_trace(
    z = ~tf_current_map$`2024`, 
    #text = ~paste(State, "has had\n", tf_current_map$`2024`, "bills introduced"), 
    span = I(0),
    locations = ~abbr, 
    locationmode = 'USA-states',
    colorscale = list(
      list(0, custom_colors[1]),
      list(custom_breaks[2] / max(custom_breaks), custom_colors[2]),
      list(custom_breaks[3] / max(custom_breaks), custom_colors[3]),
      list(custom_breaks[4] / max(custom_breaks), custom_colors[4]),
      list(1, custom_colors[5])),
    zmin = min(custom_breaks),
    zmax = max(custom_breaks),
    # State border colors/thickness
    marker = list(line = state_border),
    # To do: list min/max
    colorbar = list(
      tickvals = list(custom_breaks[1], custom_breaks[5]),
      ticktext = list(custom_breaks[1], custom_breaks[5])),
    hovertext = ~paste0(`State`),
    showscale = FALSE
    ) %>%
  colorbar(title = "Bills") %>%
  layout(geo = geo_test, 
         font = alexandria,
         title =  list(
           text = ~paste0(updated_total_bills, 
                          ' Anti-Trans Bills Have Been', 
                          "<br>", 
                          'Introduced in 2024'),
           font = list(size = 20)),
         margin = list(l = 50, r = 50, b = 100, t = 50),
         annotations = list(
      list(
        text = 'Data From: Trans Formations Project, LegiScan',
        font = list(size = 10),
        margin = list(l = 10, r = 10, b = 10, t = 20, pad = 4),
        #height = 200,
        showarrow = FALSE,
        xref = 'paper', x = 0.5,
        yref = 'paper', y = -0.2,
        xanchor = 'left', yanchor = 'top'))
  )


Could you edit your post to include the plotly or leaflet code that you've tried so we can get a better idea of the kind of interactivity you're looking for? Either package can do this if fed the right data format (e.g., sf or GeoJSON). For instance, you could use my_data <- tigris::states() |> tigris::shift_geometry() |> sf::st_transform(4326) and then plot this in leaflet with leaflet() |> addPolygons(data = my_data). You may not be able to add basemap tiles, however, since Alaska and Hawaii will be shifted.

Hi, @cristian-vargas! I am really just looking for a pinch-zoom and pop-up on tap interactivity, as I tried to note in my question. AFAIK (and after spending a bunch of time looking through Plotly boards), it seems that Plotly in R doesn't do pinch-zoom on mobile. I'll edit to post some code in the next few minutes, as well as a prototype map, and I don't need basemap tiles, honestly—just state outlines/states is wonderful.
Thank you for the shift_geometry option, too, I'll give it a try shortly!
